# Network iOS : Background / MainThread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, background, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I'm trying to put an image in cell.image.
If the image is already loaded ( and so, in cache ), I do it. Otherwise, I download it in background using `sendAsynchronousRequest`.

This is my code :

```
var image = self.imageCached[urlString] as? UIImage
    
    if image {
        cell.imageView.image = image
    
    } else {
        
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString))
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), { response, data, error -> Void in
            
            image = UIImage(data: data)
            self.imageCached[urlString] = image;
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                cell.imageView.image = image
            })
        })
    }
```

But I have still some things that are unclear :

1. The `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` is doing the task in background but `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()` seems to do things in main thread (because of the name 'mainQueue'). So what is the real things?  The block inside the instruction is in background or main thread? Because if it's on the main thread, it's not necessary to come back to the main thread in order to update the UI.
2. I heard that `NSURLConnection` is used for little quick requests. It that true? Because when I use `NSURLSession` instead this asynchronous `NSURLConnection` request for downloading all cell image, it's longer that `NSURLConnection`.

   So when should I use `NSURLConnection` and when to use `NSURLSession`? (for example : json data or quick login check from api)
3. Also, when I'm quiting the app, it seems the system cache works. But how? Because I'm only storing the image in array. So why after closing the app, it seems it's always cached?

Comment: As an aside, if this is in a table/collection view, remember that you cannot assume that `cell` is still valid by the time the async request finishes (because cells are reused). Typically, inside that `dispatch_async` block, you'd query the table/collection view with `cellForXXXAtIndexPath` (not to be confused with the similarly named method in your view controller) to see if the cell was still visible, and use that new pointer for updating the image.

Comment: Ok and What about the cell outside the dispatch ( in the first if ), it's possible that it's invalid ?

Comment: The first one (where you say `if image ...`) is fine, because that's happening synchronously in the flow of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. But anything inside an asynchronous request (e.g. inside `sendAsynchronousRequest`) or in a `dispatch_async` should check to see if the cell is still visible before trying to use it. If you don't, especially on a slow connection, you might see the wrong cells getting updated (which sometimes manifests itself of a flickering of cells image from one to another).

Answer (score 1):

1. The `queue` parameter specifies which queue the completion block will be run on, not on which queue the network operation will be performed.

   As an aside, that means that the additional dispatch to the main queue inside the current implementation of the completion block/closure is redundant.

   Note, a little surprisingly, the `imageWithData`, itself, can (especially if the images are large) take more than a few milliseconds to run, which can lead to a observable (though very slight) stuttering in the UI if you do `imageWithData` in the main thread. Generally you won't even notice this, but if this code was in a table/collection view, you'll see it if scrolling quickly. So, you might want to use an operation queue other than `mainQueue` as the `queue` parameter of your network request, and then keep the code that dispatches the final UI update to the main queue. The difference may be barely noticeable, but it's a refinement to consider if you want to keep your scrolling silky smooth. It just depends upon the context in which this code appears.
2. It's not my experience that `NSURLSession` is any slower than `NSURLConnection` is. I wonder (especially without seeing code for `NSURLSession` implementation), if your `NSURLSession` implementation is not caching for some reason.

   The general counsel is that you'd use `NSURLConnection` if you need to support iOS versions prior to 7.0, otherwise use `NSURLSession`.
3. The caching that you're seeing is that which is transparently provided by `NSURLConnection` and/or `NSURLSession`, completely separate from any app-level caching you might be effectively doing with your array.

Comment: Thanks for your response. About the 1) I understand nothing ^^

Comment: On point 2, I saw that `NSURLSession` sample you briefly shared with us and didn't see anything obvious. I just compared `NSURLSession.sharedSession()`, `NSURLSession(configuration)`, and `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` and they were comparable, so I can't comment without more information (including example URL that exhibits the behavior you describe). The only thing I can wonder is that there might be differences in the default caching between the two classes (Apple has never been very open about the specific criteria), but that could be remedied by explicitly specifying your cache.

Comment: Sorry, about Rob it was just an error of mine. It's ok about that. But like I said, it's not, now , the 2) the problème but the 1) ..

In any case, thanks for what you do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm unclear as to whether you still have any question, or whether I've answered it...